# hashCode does not change in the method when changing parameters

Tags: java, object, methods, hashcode

there is a problem i am facing. I am trying to compare hashCodes for two objects in the method. It shows two different hashCodes for the objects, but when i change objects places, hashCode remains the same. Here is the part of the code:

```
public class Cat {
    public int age;
    public int weight;
    public int strength;

    public Cat() {
    }

    public boolean fight(Cat anotherCat) {
        int score = 0;
        if (this.age > anotherCat.age)
            score++;
        if (this.weight > anotherCat.weight)
            score++;
        if (this.strength > anotherCat.strength)
            score++;

        if ((this.weight == anotherCat.weight) && (this.strength == anotherCat.strength) && (this.age == anotherCat.age)) {
            long a = this.hashCode();
            long b = anotherCat.hashCode();
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);


        }


        return score >= 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        cat1.weight = 10;
        cat1.strength = 5;
        cat1.age = 7;
        Cat cat2 = new Cat();
        cat2.weight = 10;
        cat2.strength = 5;
        cat2.age = 7;
        System.out.println(cat1.fight(cat2));

    }
}
        cat1.fight(cat2)
        951007336
        2001049719 

        cat2.fight(cat1) 
        951007336
        2001049719
```

why is that so?

Comment: Could you show us the implementation of the `Cat` class?

Comment: Please provide some *compilable* code.

Comment: I strongly discourage you to have the fields set to `public`. It's better to change them to `private` and add *setters* for the fields. This is way of *encapsulation*. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm).

Answer (score 3):

> hashCode does not change in the method when changing parameters

That is normal behavior for `Object.hashCode`.  And your `Cat` method is using the inherited `hashCode`.

The implementation for `hashCode` in `Object` returns an "identity hashcode"; i.e. one that is computed (somehow) from the object's identity.  This won't change for the lifetime of the object.

If you want a hashcode value that depends on the fields of your object, then you need to override `Object.hashCode`;  e.g.

```
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return age + (weight * 31) + (strength * 31 * 67);
   }
```

Note that hashcode values are NOT guaranteed to be unique.  Uniqueness is not part of the *equals / hashcode contract*.  (Lots of cats could have the same hashcode.)

Also, changing hashcodes can be a problem.  If you cause the hashcode of an object to change while it is a member of a `HashSet` or a key in a `HashMap`, the data structure will behave inconsistently.